# Diferença entre "git add --all", "git add ." e "git add -u"

Tags: git

O comando `git add --all` me parece igual ao comando `git add .`, mas não tenho certeza se eles são a mesma coisa. Caso não sejam, qual a diferença entre eles?

Fico em dúvida também em relação ao `git add -u` e `git add *`.

Comment: Todas essas opções tem em comum o seguinte: se vc não especificar o caminho, todos os arquivos são atualizados. De fato, as peculiaridades diferem entre `git add --all` e `git add -u`. Dê uma olhada na documentação do [git add][https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add] para que vc tenha um melhor entendimento!

Comment: @GabrielHardoim, o link está quebrado.

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add tenta com esse

Comment: Sobre a questão de não especificar o caminho  eu já conhecia, mas gostaria de saber se tem alguma questão mais processual por trás. Por exemplo, coloca em stage todas as mudanças, ou algo desse tipo.

Comment: Isso não sei dizer ao certo.. Mas a documentação mostra a diferença entre o --all e o -u

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Existem diferenças](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572549/difference-between-git-add-a-and-git-add) entre estes comandos, mas vai depender da versão do Git que está usando.

Como exemplo, na versão 1.x do Git, os comandos `git add --all` e `git add .` são diferentes, mas na versão 2.x estes dois comandos são iguais.

Veja as tabelas abaixo mostrando as diferenças. No Git **versão 1.x**:

| Comando | Novos | Modificados | Removidos | Explicação |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| git add --all | X | X | X | Coloca todos arquivos (novos, modificados e removidos) no index/stage |
| git add . | X | X |  | Coloca no Stage apenas arquivos novos e modificados |
| git add -u |  | X | X | Coloca no Stage apenas arquivos modificados e removidos |

No Git **versão 2.x**:

| Comando | Novos | Modificados | Removidos | Explicação |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| git add --all | X | X | X | Coloca todos arquivos (novos, modificados e removidos) no index/stage |
| git add . | X | X | X | Coloca todos arquivos (novos, modificados e removidos) no index/stage¹ |
| git add -u |  | X | X | Coloca no Stage apenas arquivos modificados e removidos |

> Fico em dúvida também em relação ao git add -u e git add *

O primeiro comando, obedecendo a tabela acima, irá adicionar os arquivos incluindo aqueles que começam com `.`. O `git add *` irá adicionar todos os arquivos da mesma forma que o `git add .`, mas ignorando os arquivos que começam com `.`.

<sup>1. O `git add .` adiciona apenas novos arquivos que estão no diretório atual. Se você tem um novo diretório , o `git add -A` vai adicionar este diretório no stage mas o `git add .` não fará isto.</sup>

Comment: Obrigado! Era isso mesmo que procurava!

Comment: Qual o motivo do negativo?

Comment: Não negativei a resposta

Comment: @JoãoPedroSchmitz, sem problemas, com certeza foi algum outro usuário. Obrigado por responder! A pergunta é para o autor do negativo, caso ele algum dia visite a pergunta novamente.

Answer (score 6):

Os comandos *git add --all* e *git add .*, podem parecer iguais mas fazem ações bem diferentes:

- `git add --all`: adiciona ao staging arquivos desde a raiz do repositório passando por todos os subdiretórios, e aqui está a diferença, não importa se você está na raiz ou no sub-diretório.
- `git add .`: usando o ponto, será adicionado ao stagging somente os arquivos a partir do diretório que você está, e os sub-diretórios deste.

Exemplo:

Usando a seguinte estrutura de arquivos e pastas como exemplo:

```
.
.gitignore
src
├── Controllers
│   └── HomeController.cs
├── HelloWorld.csproj
├── Models
│   └── ErrorViewModel.cs
├── Program.cs
├── Properties
│   └── launchSettings.json
├── Startup.cs
├── Views
│   ├── Home
│   │   ├── About.cshtml
│   │   ├── Contact.cshtml
│   │   ├── Index.cshtml
│   │   └── Privacy.cshtml
```

Considerando que somente o .gitignore está versionado no repositório, se você estiver no diretório *src/Views/Home* e executar:

```
git add .
```

Serão adicionados os arquivos: About.cshtml, Contact.cshtml, Index.cshtml e Privacy.cshtml.
Mas não serão adicionados os arquivos de outros diretórios, por exemplo: HomeController.cs, que está no diretório *src/Controllers/*.

- `git add *`: vai funcionar exatamente igual ao comando anterior, adicionando somente os arquivos da pasta corrente ao que o comando foi executado.
- `git add -u`, ou `git add --update` vai fazer um update na stagging nos arquivos que já estão sendo rastreados pelo Git.

Continuando a usar o exemplo anterior, depois de executar o `git add .` e em seguida `git commit -m "Primeiro"`, ainda existirão arquivos a serem adicionados ao respositório; então, edita-se o arquivo About.cshtml. Executando um `git status`, o estado do repositório será:

```
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   About.cshtml

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        ../../Controllers/
        ../../HelloWorld.csproj
        ../../Models/
        ../../Program.cs
        ../../Properties/
        ../../Startup.cs
        ../Shared/
        ../_ViewImports.cshtml
        ../_ViewStart.cshtml
        ../../appsettings.Development.json
        ../../appsettings.json
        ../../wwwroot/
```

Executando o comando `git add -u`, somente o arquivo About.cshtml é colocado na área de staging, os outros arquivos que ainda não estão no repositório continuam como não rastreados pelo Git. Esse comando vai funcionar tanto para arquivos modificados como para apagados.